# Modifying values inside an action using action filters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I read different stack Q/As about this but I'm still very confused...

So when a request is sent to controller it does some process and sends some result back to a view. Now, just before it sends the data to the view, I need to look through its data and make some changes and then simply allow the operation to continue normally.

Two example of methods I want to modify their data:

```
[NonAction]
protected virtual void PrepareBlogPostModel(BlogPostModel model, BlogPost blogPost, bool prepareComments)
{
    model.Id = blogPost.Id;
    model.MetaTitle = blogPost.MetaTitle;
    model.MetaDescription = blogPost.MetaDescription;
    model.MetaKeywords = blogPost.MetaKeywords;
    model.SeName = blogPost.GetSeName(blogPost.LanguageId, ensureTwoPublishedLanguages: false);
    model.Title = blogPost.Title;
    model.Body = blogPost.Body;
    model.BodyOverview = blogPost.BodyOverview;
    model.AllowComments = blogPost.AllowComments;
    model.CreatedOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(blogPost.CreatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    model.Tags = blogPost.ParseTags().ToList();
    model.NumberOfComments = blogPost.CommentCount;
    model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnBlogCommentPage;
}

[NonAction]
protected virtual BlogPostListModel PrepareBlogPostListModel(BlogPagingFilteringModel command)
{
    var model = new BlogPostListModel();
    model.PagingFilteringContext.Tag = command.Tag;
    model.PagingFilteringContext.Month = command.Month;
    model.WorkingLanguageId = _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id;

    DateTime? dateFrom = command.GetFromMonth();
    DateTime? dateTo = command.GetToMonth();

    IPagedList<BlogPost> blogPosts;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Tag))
    {
        blogPosts = _blogService.GetAllBlogPosts(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id,
        _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id,
        dateFrom, dateTo, command.PageNumber - 1, command.PageSize);
    }
    else
    {
        blogPosts = _blogService.GetAllBlogPostsByTag(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, 
        _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id,
        command.Tag, command.PageNumber - 1, command.PageSize);
    }

    model.PagingFilteringContext.LoadPagedList(blogPosts);
    model.BlogPosts = blogPosts.Select(x =>
                      {
                          var blogPostModel = new BlogPostModel();
                          PrepareBlogPostModel(blogPostModel, x, false);
                          return blogPostModel;
                      }).ToList();

    return model;
}
```

one of these is then called here:

```
public ActionResult List(BlogPagingFilteringModel command)
{
    if (!_blogSettings.Enabled)
        return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");

    var model = PrepareBlogPostListModel(command);
    return View("List", model);
}
```

I need to modify the, let's say `CreatedOn` value for each blog post in my action filter:

```
public class ChangeDateActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
       // making sure we are modifying the right controller and action data
        if (controllerContext.Controller is BlogController && actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("PrepareBlogPostListModel", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return new List<Filter>() { new Filter(this, FilterScope.Action, 0) };
        }

        return new List<Filter>();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // modifying CreatedOn for each blog post here, but how?
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArghyaC I'll fix it now.

Comment: @VSG24 What's benefit of `ActionFilter` here? Why not simply perform that check in your business logic or in the action?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I'm not supposed to alter the controller at all.

Comment: @RezaAghaei How exactly do I access the model properties and change them?? Please provide an example as an asnwer.

Comment: I'll post an example for you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the action or business logic, it's better to put the logic in action or your business logic methods, But if you can't change or override controller methods, you can create an `ActionFilter` and override `OnActionExecuted` and modify the model using `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model`:

```
public class SomeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as YourModelType;

        //Modify model here or assign a new object to it.

        //Then pass the modified model to view
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model= model;

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model= modifiedModel;` Is what I was looking for.

Comment: That's it, pay attention to override `OnActionExecuted`. I mistakenly said `OnActionExecuting` in above comments.